# EIGRP Holding Time Expire on VLAN Interfaces

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, eigrp

I configure 2 Layer 3 Switches with VLANs and EIGRP route.

But it always return a message like this :

```
%DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: IP-EIGRP 2019: Neighbor 192.168.20.253 (Vlan20) is down: holding time expired

%DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: IP-EIGRP 2019: Neighbor 192.168.10.253 (Vlan10) is down: holding time expired
```

**My running-configuration on DSW-01 (Layer 3 switch) :**

```
Current configuration : 2260 bytes
!
version 16.3.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname DSW-01
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
ip routing
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30 priority 24576
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
no switchport
ip address 192.168.254.1 255.255.255.252
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
channel-group 1 mode active
spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
channel-group 1 mode active
spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
mac-address 0060.70b4.0801
ip address 192.168.10.254 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 192.168.10.253
!
interface Vlan20
mac-address 0060.70b4.0802
ip address 192.168.20.254 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 192.168.20.253
!
router eigrp 2019
network 192.168.254.0 0.0.0.3
network 192.168.10.0
network 192.168.20.0
network 192.168.30.0
auto-summary
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.254.2
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
login
!
!
!
!
end
```

**And for the DSW-02 (Layer 3 Switch) :**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2369 bytes
!
version 16.3.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname DSW-02
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp pool lan
network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.10.254
option 150 ip 172.16.100.1
ip dhcp pool lan2
network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.20.254
option 150 ip 172.16.100.1
dns-server 1.1.1.1
!
!
!
no ip cef
ip routing
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30 priority 28672
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
no switchport
ip address 192.168.254.5 255.255.255.252
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
channel-group 1 mode passive
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
channel-group 1 mode passive
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
mac-address 0005.5e34.e101
ip address 192.168.10.253 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan20
mac-address 0005.5e34.e102
ip address 192.168.20.253 255.255.255.0
!
router eigrp 2019
network 192.168.254.4 0.0.0.3
network 192.168.10.0
network 192.168.20.0
network 192.168.30.0
auto-summary
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Any solution for this problem?

Regards

Kevin Tim

Comment: You are losing connectivity between your switches.   When it happens, try tp ping from one switch to the other.  Then you can troubleshoot that.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but auto-summarization in EIGRP is dangerous. That can cause you to advertise classful summary routes.  It also seems weird that you are manually setting Mac addresses. Is turning off cef default on that platform?  I get suspicious of config elements I do not understand.

Comment: You've created the SVIs (vlan interfaces) but have you also created the vlans 10, 20, 30?

Comment: @DarrellRoot agreed that cef should be on all the time but disabling it can help in troubleshooting since you get more logging of transit frames / packets

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see your eigrp config seems fine, since you are using vlans for EIGRP, the first thing you need to verify is if the L2 instances of the vlans are stable/STP. 
Then when the issue happens do we maintain unicast reachability via ping/icmp between both, do we keep the multicast reachability as well via ping to 224.0.0.10 --> neighbor should respond if it is listening to the EIGRP multicast address ?

Regards,

VSL